# get the last output for non-padded entry from tf.nn.dynamic_rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use an RNN in an all-to-one mode (only one output at the end). In TensorFlow, one can use:

```
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(lstm_num_units)

output, _  = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, embed, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Where the output contains the output at all time steps `[0, max_time-1]`, and the `max_time` is the length of the longest input in the batch.

Now, I would like to get the last output for every input in the batch. Let me be clearer. All the implementations that I have seen on the net, use `output[:,-1]` as the last output. However, for the inputs which have been padded, this would imply that the output is from the padded input.

Therefore, the questions:

1. How justified it is to use just `output[:,-1]`
2. Is there an easy way to select the last entry for the non-padded value in TensorFlow, which, in general, will be at different time steps for every input in the batch. Somehow, I found it a bit hard to do the necessary manipulations with the TensorFlow tensors, even when I have the original lengths of all input sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code:

```
_, state  = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, embed, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=some_placeholder)

last_output = state.h
```

Don't forget to add a `sequence_length` parameter in the call to `dynamic_rnn` if you want the sequence lengths to vary.

Alternatively, you could use `tf.gather_nd`.